# Ubuntu SDK mounts

Tags: sdk

After installing Ubuntu SDK there is alot of new stuff in my 'df' output:

```
click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-amd64   94G   15G   75G  17% /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-amd64- blabla several lines
```

How do I remove this (still keeping the SDK)?

ty